# acceptably safe download file

Tags: php, security, download

I have seen this question around many times, but it has to do much with code that works to force download, and I don't think I found anything about "security" issues that may arise with that. I want people to download things after login (to prevent hotlinking). 
I am trying to juggle this with htaccess and PHP. The PHP file checks the login, and I also have OpenId (something).  The download part is as follows:

```
    $url = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/myfolder/{$myfile}";

    if(!is_file($url)) { 
   //whatever
    }elseif (is_file($url)){

    switch($url['extension']) {
            case 'pdf': $ext = 'application/pdf'; break;
            case 'zip': $ext = 'application/zip'; break;
            case 'pps': $ext = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'; break;
            case 'pptx': $ext = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'; break;
            case 'docx': $ext = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'; break;
            default: $ext = 'application/force-download';
        }    
        header('Pragma: public');   
       header('Expires: 0'); 
       header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
       header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
       header("Content-Type: application/download");      
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Cache-Control: private',false);
       header('Content-Type: '.$ext);
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($url).'"');
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Connection: close');
       readfile($url);   
       exit();
     }
```

`Myfolder` is protected with htaccess that denies to all.
I am uncertain of whether this is safe enough though, so I am asking before I do something terribly unsafe. I have read around that people can download "your precious scripts" but I don't see how (PHP, as far as I know, isn't downloadable). Do you think I have serious vulnerabilities, except XSS, which, by the way, is handled somewhere in that page?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this script even work. You can't echo something before headers.

Comment: sorry that was debug. But it actually works, unfortunately, so let me edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's already been mentioned in the comments, you can't send headers after sending content with `echo`.

Also: be sure to sanitize the `$myfile` var you use to generate the file path, then use `realpath` to double-check that the resulting path is on the list of "allowed" paths. Otherwise someone might be able to pass something like `../../../supersecret/file` and you're in trouble.

Comment: terribly sorry for the echo and I edited. When I do something from scratch, I tend to test the basics and then build up something a bit more complex. If I didin't forget to take out what's in the helloworld test (did to get to {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} because I'm silly and had typed it wrong) before posting it would have been better. $myfile is sanitized but I didn't copy that part (it's already too long). I pass the var it with $_POST (because get worries me as a general rule) and sanitize it. Thanks for the realpath. Do you think I should check the file extension before the download too?

Comment: If the directory you allow the downloads from contains downloadable files only (which would be a good idea) then only checking the path should be enough.